# jquery inserting all stylesheets into iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, wysiwyg

How can I insert all of a parent window's stylesheets into an iframe's head(samedomain)?

My attempted code based on a similar question:

```
function () {
    var d = frames[0].document;
    var stylesheets = $("link").outerhtml;
    d.open();
    d.write(
    '<html><head>'+
    stylesheets + 
    '<style type="text/css">'+
    '<\/style><\/head><body><\/body><\/html>'
    );
    d.close();
}
```

Clearly this does not work outside of IE. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Attempt based on Anthony's answer:

```
    $("link[type='text/css']").each(function() {
        var stylesheet = $(this).clone();                                    
        $("iframe").contents().find("head").append(stylesheet);
    });
```

Comment: written by the first function, which creates doubt, do iframes contains HTML or are blank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An issue with the selected answer is that it uses `.html()`, which returns only the inner html contents of that element, not the element itself.  Here is a working solution:

```
$("link[type='text/css']").clone().appendTo($("iframe").contents().find("head"));
```

Comment: The type attribute is optional on stylesheet link tags in HTML5, better to use `$("link[rel='stylesheet']")`.

Comment: Or go for the full trifecta: `$("link[rel='stylesheet'], link[type='text/css'], link[href$='.css']")`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("link[type='text/css']").each(function() {
     var stylesheet = $(this).html();
     $("iframe").contents().find("head").append(stylesheet);
     });
```

Comment: you mean this.clone right? Because otherwise that would move the stylesheet. Still, I'm not getting this to work.

Comment: No, i meant append, but I also meant to specify to append the html, sorry. Does the edit work? If not, make sure the iframe selector works. Something simple like `alert($("iframe").contents().find("title").text()`. The iframe code is straight from jquery.

Comment: Sorry, I messed some little thing up, but the vers I have in the question would work. Thanks.